# Detecting browser in php return default browser

Tags: php

I am just a beginner in php. Am using xampp 1.7.3 and mozilla Firefox browser version 46.0.1 
I downloaded the full_php_browscap.ini file and kept in the directory C:\xampp\php\extras , changed the browscap section in php.ini with the following

```
[browscap]
; http://php.net/browscap
browscap = "C:\xampp\php\extras\full_php_browscap.ini"
```

I ran the following code in the default index.php

```
$browser = get_browser(null, true);
echo $browser['browser'];
```

After this I am supposed to get the result of browser name like 'Firefox' but it shows me 'Default Browser'. Can you figure out where it went wrong.

This type of question has been answered before, that's why I tried to document step by step what I tried.

Comment: Also that I am using windows8 64 bit !!

Answer (score 0):

Are you using browscap for security reasons? If you only need it in your PHP script you can use `get_browser()`

```
<?php
$browser = get_browser(null, true);
print_r($browser);
```

This will output an array of the browser's capabilities, and you can access them like:

```
<?= $browser['parent']; ?>
```

or

```
<?= $browser['browser']; ?>
```

More info: http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php

Comment: OP is using your code but receiving wrong results. `$browser = get_browser(null, true); echo $browser['browser'];`